# A.e. global existence of solution to 'encased' n-body problem already somewhere in the literature?

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, celestial-mechanics

In the study of the Newtonian n-body problem, it seems that [Von Zeipel's theorem](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Emcgehee/publications/McGehee1986/McGehee1986ExpositionesMath4p335.pdf) and [Saari's theorem concerning the improbability of collision singularities](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1973-181-00/S0002-9947-1973-0321386-0/home.html) ought to lend themselves to a nice synthesis in the case of a gravitational n-body problem which is encased in a bounded domain, say with elastic walls, i.e. an IVP of the form
$$
\begin{cases}
\ddot{x}_j  = -x_j f(|x_j|)+\displaystyle{\sum_{k\in \{1,\ldots,n\}\setminus \{j\}}}\mu_k\dfrac{x_k-x_j}{\|x_k-x_j\|^3}\\
x_j(0) = x_j^*\in B(0,R) \\
\dot{x}_j(0) = v_j^*\in \mathbb{R}^3
\end{cases}\quad\forall j\in \{1,\ldots,n\}
$$
where

- $(\mu_k)_{1\leq k \leq n}\in (0,+\infty)^n$,
- the $x_j^*$ are a priori all distinct and
- $f\in C([0,R),\mathbb{R})$ is such that $\lim_{r\uparrow R}f(r)=+\infty$.(*)

The purported claim about this IVP would be that a maximal solution exists with time domain $\mathbb{R}$ for (Lebesgue-)a.e. $(x_j^*,v_j^*)_{1\leq j\leq n}\in (B(0,R)\times \mathbb{R}^3)^n$. Was this purported synthesis already demonstrated somewhere in the literature?

(*) I have modelled the elastic reflection (at the boundary $\partial B(0,R)$) in a 'smeared' way to ease the presentation of the IVP. I would a priori not expect a qualitative difference with the model where one in stead opts for a "hard" elastic wall at $\partial B(0,R)$.